# Cannot find the correct projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm working with some raster data I downloaded. The problem is I can't manage to find the correct projection for this file. It should work with WGS84 (as shown in the image below) but it's displaced towards the south relative to the borderline. The QGIS plugin "Projestions" doesn't suggest any either.
Any ideas about how this can be solved?

[image]

The output of gdalifno:

```
Warning 1: Latitude grid not spaced evenly.  Setting projection for grid spacing is within 0.1 degrees threshold.Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Size is 631, 539
Origin = (-5.811904761904762,44.722040824551812)
Pixel Size = (0.023809523809524,-0.018239630129158)
Metadata:
  lat_rho#axis=Y
  lat_rho#field=lat_rho, scalar
  lat_rho#long_name=latitude of RHO-points
  lat_rho#standard_name=latitude
  lat_rho#units=degree_north
  lat_uv#axis=Y
  lat_uv#field=lat_uv, scalar
  lat_uv#long_name=latitude of UV-points
  lat_uv#standard_name=latitude
  lat_uv#units=degree_north
  lon_rho#axis=X
  lon_rho#field=lon_rho, scalar
  lon_rho#long_name=longitude of RHO-points
  lon_rho#standard_name=longitude
  lon_rho#units=degree_east
  lon_uv#axis=X
  lon_uv#field=lon_uv, scalar
  lon_uv#long_name=longitude of UV-points
  lon_uv#standard_name=longitude
  lon_uv#units=degree_east
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.0
  NC_GLOBAL#date_created=07-Aug-2020 10:06:17 CET
  NC_GLOBAL#file=WMOP surface his file
  NC_GLOBAL#format=netCDF-3 classic file
  NC_GLOBAL#fullname=Balearic Islands Coastal Observing and Forecasting System
  NC_GLOBAL#institution=SOCIB
  NC_GLOBAL#publisher_email=info@socib.es
  NC_GLOBAL#publisher_name=SOCIB
  NC_GLOBAL#publisher_url=www.socib.es
  NC_GLOBAL#version=WMOPv2.2r ROMS Forecast (with data assimilation)
  NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={ocean_time}
  NETCDF_DIM_ocean_time_DEF={25,6}
  NETCDF_DIM_ocean_time_VALUES={1647561600,1647572400,1647583200,1647594000,1647604800,1647615600,1647626400,1647637200,1647648000,1647658800,1647669600,1647680400,1647691200,1647702000,1647712800,1647723600,1647734400,1647745200,1647756000,1647766800,1647777600,1647788400,1647799200,1647810000,1647820800}
  ocean_time#axis=T
  ocean_time#calendar=gregorian
  ocean_time#field=time, scalar, series
  ocean_time#long_name=time since initialization
  ocean_time#units=seconds since 1968-05-23 00:00:00 GMT
  v#coordinates=ocean_time lat_uv lon_uv
  v#field=v-velocity, scalar, series
  v#long_name=v-momentum component
  v#standard_name=northward_sea_surface_velocity
  v#time=ocean_time
  v#units=meter second-1
  v#_FillValue=-nan
Geolocation:
  LINE_OFFSET=0
  LINE_STEP=1
  PIXEL_OFFSET=0
  PIXEL_STEP=1
  SRS=GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
  X_BAND=1
  X_DATASET=NETCDF:/roms_wmop_surface_20200807.nc":lon_uv
  Y_BAND=1
  Y_DATASET=NETCDF:/roms_wmop_surface_20200807.nc":lat_uv
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -5.8119048,  44.7220408) 
Lower Left  (  -5.8119048,  34.8908802) 
Upper Right (   9.2119048,  44.7220408) 
Lower Right (   9.2119048,  34.8908802) 
Center      (   1.7000000,  39.8064605) 
Band 1 Block=631x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=-0.797 Max=0.995 
  Minimum=-0.797, Maximum=0.995, Mean=0.036, StdDev=0.180
  NoData Value=nan
  Unit Type: meter second-1
  Metadata:
    coordinates=ocean_time lat_uv lon_uv
    field=v-velocity, scalar, series
    long_name=v-momentum component
    NETCDF_DIM_ocean_time=1647561600
    NETCDF_VARNAME=v
    standard_name=northward_sea_surface_velocity
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=0.99483668804169
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.036012467945364
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-0.79715889692307
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.18019412315803
    time=ocean_time
    units=meter second-1
    _FillValue=-nan
```

Comment: That looks more like a datum shift issue than a projection one.

Comment: can you add the output of `gdalinfo` on your raster?

Comment: Just edited the entry with the output of gdalinfo.

Comment: Approximately how many meters is the shift?  Are the vector layers in the same projection?  I'm wondering if you might try a different transformation or apply one if one hasn't been used.  As a workaround you might take a copy of your raster and georeference it to match your vector.